# Load animated image from url on android

Tags: android

I've one url 
http://radblast.wunderground.com/cgi-bin/radar/WUNIDS_composite?maxlat=38.35494788602722&maxlon=-121.87068343162537&minlat=37.180387917398&minlon=-122.96931557357311&rainsnow=1&smooth=1&frame=0&num=10&alpha=1&delay=10&cors=1&theext=.gif&nodebug=0&png=0&min=1&noclutter=0&radar_bitmap=1&noclutter_mask=1&brand=wundermap&width=800&height=1082

It has no of image animated.

I want to show the image on in my app not in browser and webview.

how to show it?

I've tried to downlaod the image and stored on sdcard.

i've checked

http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/07/android-how-to-use-animated-gif/

but i dont know how to load the gif image from sd card path.

Comment: You can't use directly **gif** image in Android

Comment: may be this would help you http://weavora.com/blog/2012/02/07/android-how-to-use-animated-gif/

Comment: yes. but i dont know how to download gif image from that url and convert to movie.